# Monogame project runs in VS but hangs when run via .exe

Tags: monogame, visual-studio

I've been working on a monogame project for a little over a week and had no problems. Today I went to test out the project outside of Visual Studio, by running directly from the .exe in the release folder. When I click on the .exe I get the cursor icon indicating something is loading, but nothing ever does. No window shows up, even though I see processes related to my game in the task manager. Also when I try to end mygame.exe in the taskmanager it doesn't work and the process still sits there.

I've tried both a Windows and Windows OpenGL monogame project and both hang once I click the exe. Does anyone have any idea why this may be or any steps I might take to track down the issue?

I'm using Windows 7, Visual Studio Community 2015 and the latest Monogame Build. My project references Farseer Physics, Lidgren, Json .Net, and my own Utility class library.

**Edit:** I tried creating a brand new Monogame project and run it without debugging in VS and it hangs the same way running from the .exe does. Also the project runs when placed on my laptop which also has monogame installed so it's nothing wrong with the project.

Comment: You can start it that way and then attach the debugger to an already running process (Debug->Attach to process), that might give you some more information. Though what I guess is happening is that visual studio starts it from a different running directory and it's trying to load some files that don't exist.

Comment: Perhaps add some logging to your project?

Comment: @craftworkgames How would I go about this, and what would I be looking for?

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden I've tried attaching the debugger but it breaks right away and I haven't been able to get any extra info. I agree that it's probably missing some file.

Answer (score 1):

So I was sitting here staring at my computer wondering why it absolutely refused to run my program, and then it hit me. I went to my anti-virus, turned it off, and voila, it works.

I don't know why Avast didn't come up with some sort of message about the program being unsafe or anything, but at least now I know what the problem was. I'm a little worried about what these means for anyone else running the same AV but at least I can start developing again.